# Portable Docker - Run Docker Image via Pen/USB Drive

Tags: docker

I have a web app and created a docker image

Is there is any portable USB docker runner so that i can carry the docker image in a pen drive and run from the usb drive?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, not entirely on the USB. Docker needs to be installed on the host machine and you likely need root access.

Comment: Can we do like this....Have portable Virtual box and install docker on a OS ..so that things would be portable....

Comment: Yes, you could do that if the VirtualBox OS is Linux.

Comment: You're welcome! If I answered your question, please mark it as the answer.